# Displaying Raster Source Information

Tags: raster, data, erdas-imagine, metadata, display

I have a large number of raster files I'm working on. I need to figure out how each of the files was processed from. I have a composite land cover map and would like to view the file names and locations that were used to create the composite. Does anyone know of a way to display such information? I am doing most my work in ERDAS.

Comment: Which software would you prefer to use to try and do this?  By asking for any of three you will be effectively asking three questions making this too broad as per the [tour].

Comment: I'm working mostly in ERDAS. My post is edited to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

QGIS has a plugin called [Image Boundary](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/imgboundary/) that does what you are after. The plugin creates a vector grid of the raster tiles and writes the raster name to the shapefile attributes.

Comment: I downloaded the plugin and it displays the file path of files within the directory, which I already know based on viewing the file directory in Window. This answers the first part of my question regarding file paths. However, I need a utility that will also display what files were processed to make the composite. For example, I have a composite land cover map (i.e., generated from two time periods), and I would like to have some idea of what files were processed to generate the file in question.